# Pass R object to R batch process?

Tags: r, batch-processing, rstudio-server

I would like to pass a PostgreSQL connection object (which is an RObject) to a batch process. Is this possible at all?

Why am I trying to do this?
I had trouble running a script that sources another script on R Studio Server. The script itself runs fine without the other script sourcing it. So this is clearly an R Studio Server Web Interface issue. However I am trying to circumvent the issue by just triggering a batch from R Studio server, after I used its nice `.rs.askForPassword` function that ships with Rstudio. I tried to following but couldn't get it to work cause to connection always ending up being expired when it was used from the batch.

```
# run file
save(con,file="conObj.Rdata")
system("R CMD batch.R") # also tried Rscript
```

batchfile looks like this

```
# batch file
load("conObj.Rdata")
#.... run some db query #
save("someObjFromDb","test.Rdata")
```

This breaks because of an expired connection object.